# Role Based Navigation Display on the Frontend

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I have a REST API served by Spring boot and I'm using JWT tokens that I generate on my backend server and give the token to the frontend application which is based on AngularJS and HTML5. I want to now control the display of the navigation based on the role of the logged in user.

The question is:

1. How could the newly logged in user with his token be identified on the frontend as admin so that I can show navigation link A, B and C for example..? Should my AngularJS fronend unpack the token?
2. When a non Admin user logs in, I can show just navigation links A and B.

How could I do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should my AngularJS fronend unpack the token?

Yes, if you want to depend on data that is in the token, use it, that is one of the benefits of JWT.

Place an `admin` or similar claim on your token, and use it. Don't worry about "security", and having an invalid token, because you are using Angular, all your views and logic is easily accessible anyway via developer tools or similar tool, and your "real" security is by checking the token on the server-side anyway.

You can use [angular-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular-jwt) module for simple JWT handling in AngularJS app.

Comment: How will the frontend unpack the token? The token is sncrypted and signed by the backend server. Should my frontend know the encryption method so that it can unpack the JWT token to get the role information out of it?

Comment: How is this JWT token safe against tampering. Somebody in the middle could intercept my requests, change the information and the frontend could completely believe this token which in this case might be wrong. For example, I can have a claim in the JWT token that has a field called role which is non-admin, but this middle man attack change that to admin. So how do I prevent against such attacks?

Comment: @sparkr The JWT token can be encrypted, but it is not required unless you keep sensetive data in it (which you should'nt). If someone in the middle can intercept your requests and change the token data, you are in a much bigger problem than the UI "thinking" you are admin. Read about JWT tokens to know how they work (maybe you don't even have a real use-case that justifies them, and regular session tokens will be a better fit). Like I wrote in the answer - take into consideration that unless you Angular app is partially rendered by the server - all of you app logic is at your client...

Comment: @sparkr and because the entire app is at the client (html views, js files etc) - you basically "don't care" about someone messing with your UI, because everybody can...You must validate the token on the server. If someone will become "admin" on the client - he may see the navigation part of the admin, but if he will for example try to access users, your API call should not return the users, because the token is invalid.

Comment: The flow is like this. User logs in with username and password, the request is sent to my server where I validate the username and password. After successful validation, I know what role this user has. I then generate a JWT token, put the username and the role in the claims section. I send this to the UI. The UI can unpack the claims and render the navigation accordingly. Assume that I somebody tampers this token before it landed on the client, so when the client sends this token back to the server upon subsequent requests, you mean to say that the JWT token validation will fail on the server?

Comment: 1) Use TLS to avoid token hickjacking. If an attacker steals a JWT, he can impersonate user 2) tampering a token will invalidate the signature. Verify signature  at server side and check permissions 3) if you really need to check validity at client side, use an asymmetric key (RSA) and verify the signature with the public key

Comment: @sparkr That is exactly what I mean. Even if the "hacker" will have access to an "admin" area in the UI (for example, will be able to click on "users"), and go the the "admin" screen (for example, see users screen), when your Angular app will send a request for the data to the server, the server should fail with 401 Unauthorized, because the token is invalid, so it will not affect your security. Also, as pedrofb said, you should (I would say - MUST) use TLS to encrypt all the incoming & outgoing data from the UI to the server, and using RSA keys is an option for client side validation.